# python3: urllib.parse import error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code like below in python 3

```
from urllib.parse import quote
quote("Stanford University")
```

When I run the code, I get below error

```
ImportError: No module named parse
```

Per [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html), `urllib.parse` is part of python3. So I did pip install urllib but then getting error `No matching distribution found for urllib`

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

```
pip --version

pip 9.0.1 from /Users/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

output of (urllib.**path**)

```
>>> import urllib
>>> print(urllib.__path__)
['/Users/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib']
```

Comment: The python module  you are running and the pip modules are probably not tied to each other. Make sure, pip installed the right packages for the python executable you are currently using.

Comment: Show us the output of `pip --version`.

Comment: What is the output of `print(urllib.__path__)`?

Comment: @JohnGordon added the version

Comment: @snakecharmerb added

Comment: Did you name your python file "urllib.py" by any chance?

Comment: @BryanOakley no

Comment: Maybe this is a difference between Anaconda and standard Python?